# Fatal error: Class 'Couchbase' not found

Tags: couchbase

I'm new to `couchbase`. When I run the following code :

```
$cb = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091", "", "", "default");
$cb->set("a", 101);
var_dump($cb->get("a"));
```

I got this error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Couchbase' not found.

Steps taken:

1. I installed couchbase-server-enterprise_3.0.3-windows_x86

> Successfully installed.

2. I downloaded C SDK library from 
   http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/c-2.4/download-install.html for my windows version and PHP Client Library form http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/php-2.0/download-links.html
3. and copied the files

> `libcouchbase.dll`
>   `php_couchbase.dll`

form the unzipped php client library file to my `/ext` folder.
and copied `php_couchbase.dll` to `/apache/` folder.

4. created a php script to test

```
$cb = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091", "", "", "default");
$cb->set("a", 101);
var_dump($cb->get("a"));
```

When I run this script I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'Couchbase' not found in.

Comment: Could be that you named your class CouchBase ? Show us the full code including code from Couchbase class so we can find out why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the syntax for the 1.x series of the PHP client but with the 2.x series installed. The syntax for 1.x and 2.x are incompatible with each other so you will have to either uninstall the 2.x client and install the 1.2 client or update your code to match the client you have installed.

An example of some code which re-creates the code in the question with the 2.x syntax would be as follows:

```
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091');
$bucket = $cluster->openBucket('default');
$bucket->insert('a', 101);
var_dump($bucket->get('a'));
```

You can find further information on using the 2.x PHP Client in the [hello Couchbase section of the documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/php-2.0/hello-couchbase.html) as well as the [2.x API reference](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-php-client-2.0.7/).

Alternatively, if you prefer the 1.x syntax you can uninstall the 2.x client and install the [1.2 client](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-php-1.2/#downloading-and-installation).